# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 (Image Upload Error)

Tags: php, image, upload

I'm having a problem when trying to upload images to a file and getting the above error. This code allows me to add new products to a store, they will update on the database with the file names it's just that they don't uploaded to the folder. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');

$addid= $_POST['addrow'];

$addproduct= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['addproduct']));
$addprice= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['addprice']));
$addprevprice= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['addprevprice']));
$adddetails= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['adddetails']));

$addimage1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage1']['name']);
$addimage1temp = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage1']['tmp_name']);
$addimage1type = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage1']['type']);
$addimage1size = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage1']['size']);

$addimage2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage2']['name']);
$addimage2temp = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage2']['tmp_name']);
$addimage2type = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage2']['type']);
$addimage2size = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage2']['size']);

$addimage3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage3']['name']);
$addimage3temp = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage3']['tmp_name']);
$addimage3type = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage3']['type']);
$addimage3size = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['addimage3']['size']);


if (!empty($addimage1))
{

    if ($addimage1type == 'image/gif' || $addimage1type == 'image/jpg' || $addimage1type == 'image/jpeg' && $addimage1size > 0 && $addimage1size < 2000000)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($addimage1temp,"../img/camera/$addimage1");

        $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details, image1)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails', '$addimage1')";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>file needs to be a jpg/gif or file size too big.</p>";
        die();  
    }
}
else
{ 
    $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails')";
}

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (!empty($addimage2))
{

    if ($addimage2type == 'image/gif' || $addimage2type == 'image/jpg' || $addimage2type == 'image/jpeg' && $addimage2size > 0 && $addimage2size < 2000000)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($addimage2temp,"../img/camera/$addimage2");
        $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details, image2)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails', '$addimage2')";
    }       
    else
    {
        echo "<p>file needs to be a jpg/gif or file size too big.</p>";
        die();  
    }
}
else
{ 
    $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails')";

}

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (!empty($addimage3)) 
{

    if ($addimage3type == 'image/gif' || $addimage3type == 'image/jpg' || $addimage3type == 'image/jpeg' && $addimage3size > 0 && $addimage3size < 2000000)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($addimage3temp,"../img/camera/$addimage3");

        $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details, image3)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails' '$addimage3')";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>file needs to be a jpg/gif or file size too big.</p>";
        die();  
    }

}
else
{ 
    $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails')";
}

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have grep all of your `INSERT` statement as follows

```
1: $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details, image1)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails', '$addimage1')";
2: $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details        )"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails')";
3: $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details, image2)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails', '$addimage2')";
4: $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details        )"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails')";
5: $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details, image3)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails' '$addimage3')";  }       
6: $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details         )"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails')";
```

**You have missed comma** on 5th INSERT....

```
"VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails' '$addimage3')";
                                                                  ^------- Here
```

### TEST

It is interesting. `'string1' 'string2'` is converted into `'string1string2'`

```
mysql> insert into test2 (a, b) values('1', '2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test2 (a, b) values('1' '2');
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

mysql> insert into test2 (a, b) values('1' '2', '3');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test2;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |
| 12   | 3    |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Improve code

- make function repeated code
- do not use `mysql_xxx()`, use `mysqli` or `PDO`
- use prepared statement for SQL Injecttion

**function style**

Not tested but following code looks better than yours.

```
<?
include('../connect.php');

$inserted = insert($_FILES['addimage1'], 'image1');
$inserted = insert($_FILES['addimage2'], 'image2');
$inserted = insert($_FILES['addimage3'], 'image3');

function insert($file, $image_col_name)
{
    $addid= $_POST['addrow'];

    $addproduct= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['addproduct']));
    $addprice= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['addprice']));
    $addprevprice= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['addprevprice']));
    $adddetails= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['adddetails']));

    $addimage = mysql_real_escape_string($file['name']);
    $addimagetemp = mysql_real_escape_string($file['tmp_name']);
    $addimagetype = mysql_real_escape_string($file['type']);
    $addimagesize = mysql_real_escape_string($file['size']); 

    if (!empty($addimage))
    {

        if (($addimagetype == 'image/gif' || $addimagetype == 'image/jpg' || $addimagetype == 'image/jpeg') && ($addimagesize > 0 && $addimagesize < 2000000))
        {
            move_uploaded_file($addimagetemp,"../img/camera/$addimage");

            $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details, $image_col_name)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails', '$addimage')";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>file needs to be a jpg/gif or file size too big.</p>";
            die();  
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails')";
    }

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error, though I'm still having problems with the upload. When I upload, it creates 4 new products in the database table which I image has something to do with 'mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` ? It also only uploads the first image...

Comment: @user3113377 Thank you for accepting my answer. Could you explain in detail? I think 3 records will be inserted into `admincamera` even if only one image is uploaded.

Comment: @user3113377 I have updated my answer to improve your PHP code. I hope this can help you!

Comment: I tried your improved code. I get no errors but this is what happens in the database, any ideas? http://i.imgur.com/CnloamI.png Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: @user3113377 Sorry, I'm not good at multi part form data using PHP. Why don't you post another question. and.. you have error in `if()` following is correct one (I guess) `($addimagetype == 'image/gif' || $addimagetype == 'image/jpg' || $addimagetype == 'image/jpeg') && ($addimagesize > 0 && $addimagesize < 2000000)`